# A question on the smallest singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Let $X(r)$ be the set of matrices $A \in M(n \times m)$, $n \leq m$, such that the norm of $A$ (largest singular value) is smaller or equal than $1$ and the smallest singular value of $A$ is smaller than $r$.

What is the largest exponent $d$ such that the volume of $X(r)$ divided by $r^d$ is uniformly bounded when $r\rightarrow 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct exponent is $d=m-n+1$. Your question is essentially the same thing as: consider a matrix with uniform i.i.d. entries taking values in $[-1,1]$ (this collection of matrices has volume that is a constant factor greater than the ones with norm at most 1); then for what proportion of such matrices is the $n$th row within $r$ of the span of the previous rows?

I am using a claim here: the $n$th singular value of an $n\times m$ matrix agrees up to a bounded factor with $\min_{i}d(r^{(i)},\mathop{lin}\{r^{(j)}\colon j\ne i\})$ that I put in a preprint that I'm just finishing.

So: given the first $n-1$ rows, you're asking what is the probability that the $n$th row lies within $r$ of their span. The span is an $(n-1)$-dimensional space and an $r$-neighbourhood of such a space has volume of the order of $r^{m-(n-1)}$.

Comment: When you say "bounded factor", you mean "dimension-dependent bounded factor", right?  Using for instance the negative second moment identity (see Lemma A.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4898.pdf) one loses a factor of $\sqrt{n}$ in either direction, and I believe this is tight.

Comment: Right. I'm not making any claims on how the constants depend on $m$ or $n$, but rather how the probability scales as a function of $r$.

Comment: PS: @TerryTao: I'm not sure about $\sqrt n$ in both directions. If the quantity is called $\alpha$, I think you can show that $\alpha/\sqrt n\le s_n(A)\le \alpha$. Or maybe I misunderstood the claim?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, there is only a loss of $\sqrt{n}$ in one direction.